# Spring MVC JDBC DataSourceTransactionManager: Data committed even after readonly=true

Tags: spring-mvc, jdbc, transactions, autocommit

I am currently developing a Spring MVC application.I have configured a JDBC TransactionManager and I am doing declarative transaction management using AOP XML.However, even if I configure the method to run on a read-only=true, it still commits the transaction.

Database : Oracle 10g

**My database-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schem...ring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">


    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${password}" />
        <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="txManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath:com/mybatis/mappers/*.xml" />
    </bean>


    <!--
        the transactional advice (what 'happens'; see the <aop:advisor/> bean
        below)
    -->
    <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
        <!-- the transactional semantics... -->
        <tx:attributes>
            <!-- all methods starting with 'get' are read-only -->
            <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" />
            <!-- other methods use the default transaction settings (see below) -->
            <tx:method name="*" read-only="true" rollback-for="RuntimeException"/>
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>

    <!--
        ensure that the above transactional advice runs for any execution of
        an operation defined by the FooService interface
    -->
    <aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut id="fooServiceOperation"
            expression="execution(* com.service.EmployeeService.*(..))" />
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="fooServiceOperation" />
    </aop:config>


</beans>
```

**My controller**

```
package com.service;

import java.util.List;

import com.mybatis.dao.EmployeeMapperInterface;
import com.spring.model.Employee;

public class EmployeeService implements EmployeeBaseService{

    EmployeeMapperInterface employeeMapper;

    public EmployeeMapperInterface getEmployeeMapper() {
        return employeeMapper;
    }

    public void setEmployeeMapper(EmployeeMapperInterface employeeMapper) {
        this.employeeMapper = employeeMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public Employee getEmployeeById(long empId){
        //retrieve from database
        List empList = employeeMapper.getEmployeeWithId(empId);
        if(empList != null && empList.size()>0){
            return (Employee) empList.get(0);   
        }
        return null;

    }




      @Override
    public long saveEmployee(Employee employee){
        long empId = 0l;
        if(employee.getEmpId()==0){
            empId  = new Long( employeeMapper.insertEmployee(employee));
        }else{
             employeeMapper.updateEmployee(employee);
             empId  =  employee.getEmpId();
        }
        try {
            System.out.println("gonna sleep");
            Thread.sleep(10);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return empId;
    }
```

How do I prevent the auto commit?I have also noticed that even if I don't put any transaction management code, the code still commits. Note, the transaction advice is however,invoked as when I put a no-rollback-for for RuntimeException and then do a 1/0, it correctly commits the data and rolls back if I put the same as rollback-for.
I have also tried out the query timeout by putting the thread on sleep, even that doesn't work, but I figure that timeout might be for an actual query, so thats fine.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is on [Spring MVC Mybatis transaction commit](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?126145-Data-commiited-even-after-readonly-true-please-help!!&p=411771&posted=1#post411771)

Detailed stack traces are also available.
To summarize,

1. Read-only is only an advice and it guarantees nothing, and I would
   really like the Spring docs to be updated about this.
2. whenever a query is executed in Oracle using Mybatis, it is in the context of a transaction which is automatically started,
   committed(or rolled back, if execption is raised),and closed by
   Mybatis.
3. Logging the application was a good idea and it helped me to find out how the actual transactions are started etc

.

Answer (score 3):

The advice `read-only` is only advice.  It is not a requirement that the underlying transaction management system prevent writes when something is marked `read-only`, it is meant more as an optimization hint, saying that this method is read only, so you don't need to worry about it changing things.   Some transaction managers will complain if changes are made in a read-only transaction, some will not.  Generally, `datasource`s acquired via JNDI will not.  In any case, you should not rely on `read-only` advice preventing changes from being written back to disk.

Your options for preventing changes from being persisted are:

- Mark the transaction `rollback only` or throw an exception having the same effect
- Detach/evict the object from the transaction session before you change it
- Clone the object and use the clone

Comment: Thanks Old Pro for the answer. I have tried option 1 as u can see with my rollback-for attribute.However, I am still not 100% sure about the read-only attribute as only being an advice. Going by http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/transaction.html, it clearly states that <quote> Read-only status: a read-only transaction does not modify any data. Read-only transactions can be a useful optimization in some cases (such as when using Hibernate).</quote>

Comment: To add on, how do I go about 2 & 3?  I want to run an update and not see the results reflected in another session, thats all.

Answer (score 1):

`DataSourceTransactionManager` begins transaction with `doBegin` method.
From this method `DataSourceUtils.prepareConnectionForTransaction` called.
Inside this method you can see following code block:

```
    if (definition != null && definition.isReadOnly()) {
        try {
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("Setting JDBC Connection [" + con + "] read-only");
            }
            con.setReadOnly(true);
        }
        catch (SQLException ex) {
```

So you could configure your logging framework to set log-level to DEBUG for `DataSourceUtils` class.

Or you could set breakpoint in this place and debug manually.

---

According to this [article](http://www.codeinstructions.com/2009/04/read-only-transactions-with-spring-and.html) I expect that `SET TRANSACTION READ ONLY` will be executed on your Oracle connection.

---

And from [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg08sql.htm#2194) we could see benefits which you receive in case of success:

> By default, the consistency model for Oracle guarantees statement-level read consistency, but does not guarantee transaction-level read consistency (repeatable reads). If you want transaction-level read consistency, and if your transaction does not require updates, then you can specify a read-only transaction. After indicating that your transaction is read-only, you can execute as many queries as you like against any database table, knowing that the results of each query in the read-only transaction are consistent with respect to a single point in time.

Comment: exactly what I was expecting and thats why its so baffling!If we do a SET TRANSACTION READ ONLY,we are not able to do any updates/inserts on the same transaction, so why does it allow here?

Comment: As I wrote in my answer - try to debug. Maybe advice is not working.

Comment: No,the advice is working, as the rollback-for and no-rollback-for works quite well.

Answer (score 1):

The read-only behaviour is strictly driver specific. Oracle driver ignores this flag entirely. For instance the same update statements executed in Oracle will modify the database if run in read-only transaction, while in HSQL2 I was getting db level exceptions.

I know no other way than explicit rollback through api or exception to prevent commit in Oracle. Also this way your code will be portable between different drivers and databases.